# react-native, debugger freezes application on macOS

Tags: macos, react-native, google-chrome

so I have a project which is fairly complex and using novel technology, on the one hand I'm using react-native-macos to build a macos app, I'm also using rxdb with some native sqlite connectors to store data, in any case, I'm facing a weird problem, I don't know when it started but now, when I try to use the chrome debugger to debug the app, the app freezes and the debugger shows nothing, except some unbalanced warning:

[image: chrome console]

if the debugger is not attached, the app runs without problems, but creating an app without a debugger is not really an option.

Now, it could be many things that are going wrong:

- As you can see I'm running multiple RCTRootView instances
- Could be react-native-macos issue, though I doubt it, it was working fine until something changed in my project (before running multiple RCTRootView instances)
- Could be something with the native SQLite connector I'm using?

Any tips on how to debug the issue would be much appreciated!

P.D. I've tried to bisect my git history to try to find the problem, but it is too complex/time consuming, since there are major compilation/db changes in the last weeks

Edit: There is a little bit more output on xcode that is not shown on chrome:

```
2020-07-11 10:16:36.315968+0200 kipu[23727:437914] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C7:1] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2020-07-11 10:16:36.316257+0200 kipu[23727:437919] [] nw_connection_get_connected_socket [C7] Client called nw_connection_get_connected_socket on unconnected nw_connection
2020-07-11 10:16:36.316343+0200 kipu[23727:437919] TCP Conn 0x600003718000 Failed : error 0:61 [61]
2020-07-11 10:16:36.343 [info][tid:main][RCTPerformanceLogger.m:79] Unbalanced calls start/end for tag 16
```

Edit 2: Now I've tried to debug the app with react-native-debugger app, that in the past has solved some problems, and it seems in this case it also does allow it to run... so I guess for now my problem is solved, I guess it has to do with my chrome installation somehow.